# How to get list out document in firestore using C#

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection called "Users", it has 2 documents "A" and "B". Now I have 2 users but later on, I may have more users, so I had to list out the document. I need to find a field called Device Name. I need to find out each user's device name.

I used the following code but it can only find the document that I listed:

```
DocumentReference documentRef = db.Collection("User").Document("A");
DocumentReference documentRef2 = db.Collection("User").Document("B");
DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = await documentRef.GetSnapshotAsync();
DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot2 = await documentRef2.GetSnapshotAsync();
if (documentSnapshot.Exists && documentSnapshot2.Exists)
{
    string deviceName = documentSnapshot.GetValue<string>("Device Name");
    string deviceName2 = documentSnapshot2.GetValue<string>("Device Name");
    MessageBox.Show($"Device Name: {deviceName}");
    MessageBox.Show($"Device Name 2: {deviceName2}");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Document does not exist.");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the device name of all users that exist inside the `User` collection, then you have to create a `Query` object and then call `GetSnapshotAsync()` like in the following lines of code:

```
Query userQuery = db.Collection("User");
QuerySnapshot userQuerySnapshot = await userQuery.GetSnapshotAsync();
foreach (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot in userQuerySnapshot.Documents)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Document data for {0} document:", documentSnapshot.Id);
    Dictionary<string, object> user = documentSnapshot.ToDictionary();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in user)
    {
        if (pair.Key == "Device Name")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }

    }
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

That's the way you should go ahead and **not** read each document individually. When there are two documents `A` and `B`, it's quite simple, but when there are multiple documents, things will become complicated in terms of writing code. So the best option that you have is to create a query and loop through the documents to get the desired data.

Comment: What do I do if I want to find Device Name value?

Comment: I see you already have edited the answer. So did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Yes, of course. I already marked it as answer.